# Testing Android In App Billing, app do not work in Test mode

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have published my app in Alpha and try to test In-app purchases.
But I don's see a testing information on the first IAP dialog. It work as a real published apps!
What is wrong? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the app as a test license account. If your email address is not added in license test accounts list, your purchase will be a real purchase that result in actual charges.

[Testing with real transactions](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases)

> With alpha/beta test groups, real users (chosen by you) can install
>   your app from Google Play and test your in-app products. They can make
>   real purchases that result in actual charges to their accounts, using
>   any of their normal payment methods in Google Play to make purchases.
>   Note that if you include test license accounts in your alpha and beta
>   distribution groups, those users will only be able to make test
>   purchases.

Check out [Setting Up Test Accounts](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup)